# Detail Hudson test reports

Tags: testing, hudson

Is there any way to force Hudson to give me more detailed test results - e.g. I'm comparing two strings and I want to know where they differ.
Is there any way to do this?
Thank you for help.

Comment: Hudson is just a continuous integration tool, agnostic of what the underlying build is. Aren't you using Maven or Ant underneath to perform your build and run test cases? That's where you should look.

Comment: Like Damien said. Also, what are you using to build your program, and what are you using to test?

Comment: I use Maven and JUnit - hudson then reports possible failures but without much detail...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not hope Hudson give the detail information, it just shows the testing messages generated by junit.

You could show the expected string and actual string when failing asserting equals between those two strings.

For example,

```
protected void compareFiles(File newFile, String referenceLocation, boolean lineNumberMatters) {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    BufferedReader referenceReader = null;
    List<String> expectedLines = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        referenceReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(FileLocator.openStream(Activator.getDefault().getBundle(), new Path("data/regression/" + referenceLocation), false)));  //$NON-NLS-1$
        expectedLines = getLinesFromReader(referenceReader);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        assertFalse("Exception occured during reading reference data: " + e, true); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }
    List<String>foundLines = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(newFile));
        foundLines = getLinesFromReader(reader);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        assertFalse("Exception occured during reading file: " + e, true); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }
    boolean throwException = expectedLines.size() != foundLines.size();
    if (throwException) {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer("\n" + newFile.toString()); //$NON-NLS-1$
        for (String line: foundLines)
            buffer.append(line + "\n"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        assertEquals("The number of lines in the reference(" + referenceLocation + ") and new output(" + newFile.getAbsolutePath()+ ") did not match!" + buffer, expectedLines.size(), foundLines.size()); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$ //$NON-NLS-3$
    }
    if (!lineNumberMatters) {
        Collections.sort(expectedLines);
        Collections.sort(foundLines);
    }
    /** Either the line matches character by character or it matches regex-wise, in that order */
    for (int i=0;i<expectedLines.size(); i++)
        assertTrue("Found errors in file (" + newFile + ")! " + foundLines.get(i) + " vs. " + expectedLines.get(i), foundLines.get(i).equals(expectedLines.get(i)) || foundLines.get(i).matches(expectedLines.get(i))); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$ //$NON-NLS-3$
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hudson supports JUnit directly. On your job configuration page, near the end, should be an option to "Publish JUnit test results report".

I'm not too familiar with JUnit itself, but I guess it produces (or has the ability to produce) and put results in an xml file. You just need to put the path of to the xml file (relative to the workspace) in the text box.

Once you do that, and create a build, you'll have a detailed report on your project page. You should then be able to click your way through the results for each test.

[image]